# STS doesn't show XSD namespaces to use with new Spring Bean Definition

Tags: spring, javabeans, spring-ide

i'm very new with spring framework and i was following this tutorial : http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-ide-1.html

According to tutorial, when i added a Spring Bean Configuration File,  i should be able to select some XSD namespaces to use with new Spring Bean Definition like this : [image: image_1]

But when i add it, it doesn't show anything like this : [image: image_2]

How can i figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

*ps: i don't know does it help you but i'm using sts 2.9.1. release on windows 7 os

edit: according to @gkamal, some packages are missing. This is the content of my project's package explorer: [image: Package Explorer Screen Shot]

Answer (score 8):

You don't have the spring jar files in your project. The namespaces & XSDs are scanned from the jars in your projects class path.

Either that or you project is not a spring project - try adding the spring nature to your project.

Comment: that's the problem. as it's displayed in 2nd. pic, there is nothing in the list.

Comment: click on the text - not just the check box

Comment: there is no text or checkbox. that's my problem. just take a look at 2nd pic on my post

Comment: Sorry I didn't read it carefully - some people face an issue where the top list is populated but the bottom list is not. I thought yours is similar. I have updated my answer.

Comment: well.. i followed this tutorial step by step : http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-ide-1.html

only difference is i directly used sts ide, not added plugins to eclipse. and my project type is "Spring Project" :s

Comment: hi, i added my package explorer's screenshot, can you tell me what's missing?

Comment: You don't have the spring jars - if you notice the tutorial there is referenced libraries that is missing form yours. You need to download the spring jars - http://www.springsource.org/download and add it to your project.

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom of the tutorial page - you will see a download link for the lib folder - you can use that as well.

Answer (score 3):

See below, the list of namespaces by JARs library. 
So you have to add the corresponding JAR in your project class path to get the namespaces you need.

```
org.springframework.aop_3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
•   aop – "http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
org.springframework.transaction_3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
•   tx - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/tx"
org.springframework.beans_3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
•   beans – "http://www/springframework.org/schema/beans"
•   c – "http://www/springframework.org/schema/c"
•   p - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/p"
•   util - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/util"
org.springframework.jms_3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
•   jms - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/jms"
org.springframework.context_3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
•   cache - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/cache"
•   context - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/context"
•   jee - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/jee"
•   lang - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/lang"
•   task - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/task"
org.springframework.jdbc_3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
•   jdbc - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
org.springframework.osgi.core_2.0.0.M2-SNAPSHOT.jar
•   bp - "http://www/osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
•   osgi - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/osgi"
•   osgix - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium"
org.springframework.oxm_3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
•   oxm - "http://www/springframework.org/schema/oxm"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure all jars are there , then close and open the project

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to properties and setting options as shown here:
[image: The answer]

Answer (score 0):

[STS 4 ->Prefrence ->Spring ->Namespaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIHXe.png)

Just uncheck the Load Namespace handlers and XSDs form projects's classpath that will come.
Beacuse everytime ide is looking for the namespaces in classpath.